# How to add a title to the top left of HTML video like YouTube

Tags: html, video

How could I add a title to the top left of video like a YouTube video?

```html
<video id="my-video-stream" controls="" width="320" height="240">
    <label id="title">My cooooool label</label>
    <source src="video/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Comment: question is in complete add more details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be you can place the `container` to wrap the `video` and `label` and then we can achieve this.

```css
.video-container {
   position: relative;
}

.title-label {
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 9;
   color: blue;
   margin-top: 5px;
   margin-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="video-container">
   <label class="title-label">My cooooool label</label>
   <video id="my-video-stream" controls="" width="320" height="240">
   <source src="video/video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
      Your browser does not support the video tag.
   </video>
</div>
```